# Play sound during standby on windows mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile-6, audio

I got an app which is started on a notify timer (which works on time, it writes into a debug log file).

This app should play a sound, but since the device is on standby, no sound is played.

I'd guess the sound device needs to be woken up, but how do I wake up the device, so I can play a sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I used CeSetUserNotificationEx to activate my program, then I could just use SndPlaySync without any problems and withour changing power policy settings.

Answer (score 0):

U have to make a call to PowerPolicyNotify. 
Refer this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908497.aspx

Comment: Oh, this 'ole thread - I long ago solved the problem by using SndPlaySync to play the sound, without having to change the power policy.